# Check that list contains the elements of all the types present in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

I have two Python lists: *components* and *signature*. I want to check whether all the **types** listed in *signature* match at least one of the elements in the component list.

Here, the signature **matches** the component list, because there is both a string and a float in *components*:

```
signature = [float, str]
components = [1.0, [], 'hello', 1]
```

Here, *signature* **does not match** *components*, because there is no list type.

```
signature = [float, list]
components = ['apple', 1.0]
```

How can I express this condition in Python 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use combination of [**`all()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [**`any()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with nested *generator expression* to achieve this. Here I am using [**`isinstance()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check for each `type` in your `signature` list matches with the object in `components` list. Using this, your custom function will be as:

```
def check_match(signature, components):
    return all(any(isinstance(c, s) for c in components) for s in signature)
```

Sample Run:

```
# Example 1: Condition is matched - returns `True`
>>> signature = [str, int]
>>> components = [1, 'hello', []]
>>> check_match(signature, components)
True

# Example 2: Condition is not matched - returns `False`
>>> signature = [float, list]
>>> components = ['apple', 1.0]
>>> check_match(signature, components)
False
```

---

**Explanation:** Above nested generator expression is comprised of two parts. First part is:

```
all(...`any()` call... for s in signature)
```

Here, I am iterating `signature` list to get each element `s` present in it. `all()` will return `True` only when all the *`...any() call...`* logic will return `True`. Else it will return `False`.

Second is the *`...any() call...`* generator expression as:

```
any(isinstance(c, s) for c in components)
```

Here, for each element `c` in `components` list, I am checking whether the type of `c` is `s` from the external generator comprehension. If any of the type matches, `any(..)` will return `True`. If none of `c` matches the condition, `any(...)` will return `False`.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you very much. I knew it would have something to do with any() and all(), but I haven't used them much in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to calculate the difference between the set of types used in components and those you have in signature.

```
unique_signatures = set(signature)
components_type = set(map(type, components))

types_not_used = unique_signatures.difference(components_type)

if len(types_not_used)==0:
    print('All types used')
else:
    print('Types not used:', types_not_used)
```

I believe there are two main advantages with this solution:

1. More efficient if your components list was long with many duplicate types, as you reduce the number of comparisons
2. How precise do you want to be in matching the class? Should subclasses pass the test? For example, `isinstance(1, object)` is `True`: is this behavior desirable to you?

Using the function provided by the (very good) answer of @Moinuddin, you have the following:

```
check_match([object], [1, 2.0, 'hello'])
Out[20]: True
```

while my answer would check `object` versus ['int', 'float', 'str'] finding no match.